# “AC BACK” option in Gigabyte BIOS is greyed out

Tags: motherboard

How can I set my desktop PC turn itself back on after a power outage?
The motherboard I am using is Gigabyte A32Mm.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to say that you can not click on that 'Always Off' default setting to see other options or you can not access it by means of arrow keys?

Comment: Questions: (1) You mean the GA-A320M motherboard? (2) Was this option available before? (3) If yes, have you tried to reset the Bios? (4) If yes, try to update it (perhaps [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios)).